# My getPrime() method does not work properly. any advice on how to fix it?

Tags: java, primes

I am trying to write a program to compute all the prime numbers in a range given by the user. however in my method get primes is not working properly because I keep getting all the number from 2 to the given range. any advice on how i can fix that?

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class Sieve
{
    private int number;

    public Sieve (int maxPrime)
    {
        number = maxPrime;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getPrimes()
    {
        Set<Integer> setNumbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();

        for(int i=2; i<=number; i++)
        {
            setNumbers.add(i);
        }

        Iterator<Integer> iter = setNumbers.iterator();

        boolean isTrue=false;

        while (iter.hasNext())  //WHILE number is more than one  
        {  
            int number1= iter.next();
            for (int i =2; i<= Math.sqrt(number); i++)
            if (number1 % i == 0)
            {  
                isTrue = true;
                break;
            }   

         } // end while     
         if(isTrue)
         {
             iter.remove();
         }
       return setNumbers;
     }
}
```

by the way i made a tester here so you can test the program if it works:

```
import java.util.Set;


public class PrimeTest
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Sieve sifter = new Sieve(100);
      Set<Integer> primes = sifter.getPrimes();
      System.out.println(primes);
      System.out.println("Expected: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 43, 41, 47, 53, 59, 61, 71, 67, 79, 73, 83, 89, 97]");

   }

}
```

Comment: Since this is for homework, let me add a comment, not related to your answer, but that will make your code easier to read, for both you and your teacher / peers: 1. Always use braces for your for and if. 2. Name your variable with clear names. IsTrue does not indicate the use of the variable, and having isTrue set to False sounds weird. Finally, you should consider adding only the prim numbers to your set instead of adding all numbers and removing those that are not prime.

Answer (score 2):

While not particularly a efficient algorithm, rather than designing your own as you seem to be doing, I'd suggest trying to implement this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

There should be several example versions online you can find.

Answer (score 0):

```
     if(isTrue)
     {
         iter.remove();
     }
     isTrue = false;
}//End while
```

will come inside the while loop and outside the for

Comment: if i should add only the prime numbers then how I generate all the numbers from 2 to the given range?